# Parse.com retrieving array as a list

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have an array under key "FoodCountArray" on parse.com of type Map.

Here is how I add it:

```
 query.getInBackground(id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(ParseObject data, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("a", "b");
                        data.add("FoodCountHistory", map);
                        data.saveInBackground();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is how I try to retrieve it.

```
query.getInBackground(id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(ParseObject onlineData, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {

                        List<Map<String, String>> objects = onlineData.getList("FoodCountArray");
                        Map<String, String> m = objects.get(0);    

                    }
```

It crashes when I do `objects.get(0);`

Comment: how about posting your logcat ?

Comment: There's a lot of messages on the console, but I think the error is `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bluetoothsensor, PID: 31890
    java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Post your full log cat in question by editing quetion